# Can we copy one column from excel and convert it to a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I use

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
list_name = df['column_name'].to_list()
```

but this is a bit long method for me. I want to copy a column and convert in python and then apply some function so that the copied text is converted to a list.

Answer (score 0):

this will read a excel column as list

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('Myfile.xlsx') #path to your file
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sheet1") #Sheet name
def Readlist(Element, Column):
    for _ in range(1,sheet.nrows):
        Element.append(str(sheet.row_values(_)[Column]))
    pass
column1 = [] # List name
Readlist(column1, 1) # Column Number is 1 here
pirnt(column1)
```

Read a specified column as list use Readlist function, intialize [] variable before using that.

Using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("path.xlsx", index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A")
mylist = list(df[0])
print(mylist)
```

Comment: This can be done with 3 lines of code using Pandas Module. I just want to copy(ctrl + c) the column, paste it in python, and then a code which will convert copied text to list.